# Swift iOS, how to make shadows appear on top of another view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, shadow, navigationbar

I am new to iOS development and I don't understand how to set the shadow of my top bar view to overlap the tableview.

If I set the topAnchor constraint of my tableView to match the bottom of the topBar and leave some padding (first image) the shadows appear, but I want to set no padding at all. If I set the top padding at zero, the shadows are hidden by the tableView (second image). How can I have zero padding between tableView and TopBar, but make the shadows appear on top of my tableView?

[image: first image]
[image: second image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep the hierarchy this way. Then set the opacity of your view to 30-40%. Rest I assume you can set the opacity of your shadow view low and make it look transparent.

[image]